# Special Price Updating unknowingly - Magento 2

Tags: product, price, products, special-price

We have an issue with the product's special price on our website. Special Price is updating for a few products unknowingly. we are not adding them manually and we suspect that it is happening with an API request.

I have verified the Magento and servers access.log but didn't find any requests of sale price update.

Could you please let me know the ways to debug?
[image]

**Note**: Website is in Adobe commerce cloud.

Answer (score 1):

If you are suspect it is API request cause this issue. You can check the API define and codes logic to chech whether it is updating special_price of product.

If you are not sure where cause this issue and can not reproduce this issue in your local environment. You can add a patch (only for debug) to monitor the special_price changes in cloud. This will very helpful to locate the issue.